# Prevent the user from moving, resizing and rotating input field in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Excel 2016 and I have an Excel worksheet with an input field. Every time I click on this input field, I'm able to move it, rotate it and resize it, but I don't want the end-user to be able to do any of these things.

[image: When I click on input field this is how it appears]

How can I prevent the user from rotating, resizing and moving the field? I just want him to only be able to edit and cancel what he has edited in that field.

Comment: I have the same issue on Mac Excel 2016. It seems design mode is activated by default

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your spreadsheet is still in design mode.

Under the `developer` tab in the ribbon, check whether the `design mode` button is activated (if it has a yellow/orange background it is active). If it is, click the button to toggle design mode.

Once out of design mode, it should no longer be possible to make layout changes to the control.

Comment: No, it's not activated. By the way I'm using excel 2016 and if I click the design mode button the background color turns dark grey not yellow/orange.